# Why css transitions not working with :target?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

CSS code.

```
   div{
        background-color: white;
    }
   :target{
        background-color: whitesmoke;
        transition:background-color 1s linear;
    }
```

transitions not working with target div why? does here animations will work?

Comment: Is there more code? :target will select the element that has an id as it's represented in the url fragment: someurl.com/home#selected-element - so :target would apply to any div like ```<div id="selected-element">```. But then still the transition property needs to be on the div, not on the target, because it needs to know that is has to transition in advance - so before applying the new styles

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might be helpful for you. Please let me know. Thanks

```css
div{
    background: #B3D3EA;
} 
    
:target{
     background: whitesmoke;
     transition:background-color 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<p><a href="#news1">Click Here 1</a></p>
<p><a href="#news2">Click Here 2</a></p>

<div id="news1"><b>New content 1...</b></div>
<div id="news2"><b>New content 2...</b></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here animations will be more helpful.

```
       :target{
            animation-name: example;
            animation-duration: 2s;
            animation-iteration-count: 1;
            animation-timing-function: linear;
        }
        @keyframes example {
            from {background-color: whitesmoke;}
            to {background-color: white;}
        }
```

it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. Helped me to get get my background-colour animating.